# TabLayout с ViewPager не обрабатывают слайды

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

Когда я пытаюсь сменить вкладку слайдом, слайд не доходит до конца, а останавливается, когда я отпускаю палец, вот так:

[image: 1]

Активити:

```
public class ActivityEasy extends Activity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(new FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs2);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_easy, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings_easy) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3; //UsefulThings.checkmods(getApplicationContext()).length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Mod #"+ (position+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кто будет тоже генерировать по шаблону, замените строчку

`mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(new 
FragmentActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());`

на

`mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`